# Trying to overlay a fragment over an existing layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

We have built a certain activity on our app, now we wanted to do a tutorial type page where we will populate the screen with dummy data and show the users what is what (they will click next to see each component)

What i thought was doing was to use a fragment (in 4+ compatibility mode) and leave the current activity as it is and if a user wants to see the tutorial, a custom UI (with dummy data) would completely overlay the current UI... But this is causing me issues.

I've mainly used this example to build what i have right now;

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentArgumentsSupport.html

When I do the "fragment.replace()", i can put in the id of any linear layout that is below the top one, and it will actually swap the content of that layout with the fragments. But it does nothing when I use the top linear layout. So i thought i would try to put the top linear layout into another linear layout, like a container and try to swap it again, but suprisingly it hasn't worked.. I've been at it for a few hours and I can't seem to figure this out..

Hopefully someone can help..

Comment: the target layout that you are replacing should be frameLayout, try it , it will work.

Comment: Hallelujah.. After few hours of trying to figure it out.. Thanks so much.. You should put that as the answer so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the target layout as `FrameLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @YashwantKumar layout on which we have another fragment??

Comment: but my layout is a scrollview then??